# Cell Cross-Reference using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have done some searching and cannot figure out the syntax for what I would like to accomplish.  I would like to have a specific, static cell on a Summary sheet automatically update to a dynamic cell on a different worksheet.  I started with the following code:

```
Sheets("Summary").Activate
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Current Billing'!R[46]C"
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='Current Billing'!R[45]C[3]+'Current Billing'!R[45]C[4]"
```

After getting some advice on a different topic for this same workbook, I now know .Select is a no-no and should be avoided.  I also know that my last row on the "Current Billing" worksheet will change when I copy the code to another workbook for billing that project.  This has led to me to modify my code to make it more fool-proof and versatile.

I have figured out how to get the the cell value to insert from my "Current Billing" sheet to my "Summary" sheet.  But if something changes on the "Current Billing" sheet, the "Summary" sheet will not automatically update.  This is the code I have that sort of works:

```
Dim ws5 As Worksheet
'ws5 is "Current Billing"
Dim ws6 As Worksheet
'ws6 is "Summary"
Dim LRowB2 As Long
Dim LRowB3 As String
LRowB2 = ws5.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
LRowB3 = ws5.Cells(LRowB2, "B")
ws6.Cells(1, "B").Formula = LRowB3
```

I tried these two code sequences, but kept getting errors:

```
Dim LRowB4 As String
Dim LRowE2 As Long
Dim LRowF2 As Long

LRowB4 = "= & ws5 & ! & LRowB3"
ws6.Cells(2, "B").Formula = "=sum(& LRowE2 &,& LRowF2 &)"
```

In short, is there a way to mimic the function of the first code procedure, but have the stability and fool-proofness of the second procedure?  And, is there a way to integrate a =Sum() formula into the second procedure so I can add two cells from "Current Billing" on the "Summary" page?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: More code is needed. You are skipping parts where you are assigning values to the variables. Also the .Formula = portions at the end are missing a lot of "" marks. Is this the code you are really using or you just worte it fast for the question?

Comment: I skipped the assignment of the variables LRowE2 and LRowE2 because they match LRowB2 above.  But the .Formula portion is what I am trying to figure out.  I don't know how or where to place all of the "" properly, or even the proper syntax of the formual to make the equation work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the formula is similar to `=SUM('Current Billing'!C9, 'Current Billing'!D9)`

This will check for errors, and is a bit more dynamic

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateSummary()
    Dim wsCB As Worksheet, lrCB As Long, cbCellC As Range, cbCellD As Range
    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet, sumCell As Range

    Set wsCB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current Billing")
    Set wsSummary = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

    lrCB = wsCB.Cells(wsCB.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    'Verify that we have the same last row for col C and D on sheet "Current Billing"
    If wsCB.Cells(wsCB.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row = lrCB Then
        Set cbCellC = wsCB.Cells(lrCB, "C")     '"Current Billing".Cell(lr, C)
        Set cbCellD = wsCB.Cells(lrCB, "D")     '"Current Billing".Cell(lr, D)
        Set sumCell = wsSummary.Cells(2, "B")   '"Summary".Cell(2, B)
        sumCell = "Invalid 'Current Billing' values"    'Default (in case of errors)

        'Check "Current Billing" cells for errors (#N/A, #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, etc)
        If Not IsError(cbCellC) And Not IsError(cbCellD) Then

            'Verify that "Current Billing" cells are numbers
            If IsNumeric(cbCellC) And IsNumeric(cbCellD) Then
                Dim cbC As String, cbD As String

                cbC = "'" & wsCB.Name & "'!" & cbCellC.Address(0, 0) 'Current Billing'!C9
                cbD = "'" & wsCB.Name & "'!" & cbCellD.Address(0, 0) 'Current Billing'!D9

                'Final format: =SUM('Current Billing'!C9, 'Current Billing'!D9)

                sumCell.Formula = "=SUM(" & cbC & ", " & cbD & ")"  'Update Summary cell
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

If the formula will contain a division, verify that the divisor is not 0

But if you are using VBA for this, you can simplify the syntax: **`sumCell = cbCellC + cbCellD`**

---

Note:

String variables become more complex when we have to use quotes inside quotes:

- `Str with ""double quotes""` can be built like this

  - `str = "Str with """"double quotes"""""`, or
  - `str = "Str with " & Chr(34) & """double quotes""" & Chr(34)`, or
  - `str = "Str with " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "double quotes" & Chr(34) & Chr(34)`
- This string `str = "Str with 'double quotes'"` is `Str with 'double quotes'`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  I appreciate the notations and explanations on every step you made, it helps me follow what is being done.  Also thank you for showing how you created the error handler, that will be my next step in making sure this spreadsheet is foolproof.  I tried so many different combinations of quotation marks and & symbols to make the syntax work, but it never did.  I now know how to carry this through and update the rest of the cells on my summary page.  Thank you again, have a great day.

Comment: I’m glad you found it helpful. I know how challenging it was for me when trying to find the optimal solutions, and this site was always helpful. A tip about figuring out quotation marks - let Excel tell you the perfect syntax; you probably started out trying to build the formula in VBA and tried to make it work in Excel. I reversed the process: build the formula in Excel, then adapted it to work in VBA

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your suggestion. I built my initial, cell specific formula using the macro recorder. That is actually how I learned how to do most of my coding. I then found this site and a couple others that have helped tremendously. Where I keep running into problems is how to write the syntax when variables are used in formulas and other parts of the code. Variables in VBA are relatively new to me, but it has been fun to learn how to make them work. I appreciate people like yourself that are willing to teach others how to work through these puzzles. Have a great day.

Comment: When building variables from strings we need to match quotation marks carefully. In this particular case, the space in the sheet name forces you to use double quotation marks. If the formula is `'Current Billing'` this is the quoted string for the Excel Formula, but in VBA we have to build another string which needs quotes as well: `"'Current Billing'"`. If the sheet name doesn't have a space we don't need to quote it in the Formula `Sheet1`, and in VBA it in: `"Sheet1"`

Comment: String variables become more complex when you have to use quotes inside quotes: `String with ""double quotations""` can be built with `str = "String with """"double quotations"""""`, or `str = "String with " & Chr(34) & """double quotations""" & Chr(34)`, or `str = "String with " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "double quotations" & Chr(34) & Chr(34)` (I'll add this note to my answer to make it easier to read)

Comment: Wow, thank you!  That is the best explanation I have seen on how to build string variables.  That is super helpful.  This info will definitely be going into my notes.  Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Workbook_SheetChange` event.  It's an "event" action that is triggered when changes are made anywhere in your workbook.  Within the event sub add code to update the value of your hard-coded/static cell with the value in your formula.

The `Workbook_SheetChange` sub must be in your workbook module (the default module name is "ThisWorkbook").

Here's an example of how you could use it.  Just update the sheet names and range addresses for the variables `myStaticCell` and `myFormulaCell`.

### In your ThisWorkbook Module:

```
Option Explicit

Public myVar As Variant ' stores last known value of static cell

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Define the locations of your formula cell and static cell.
    Dim myStaticCell As Range
    Dim myFormulaCell As Range
    Set myStaticCell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
    Set myFormulaCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")

    ' Ignore changes made directly to the static cell by comparing
    '   the sheet name and address where the workbook change
    '   occurred (variables Sh and Target which are built into the
    '   Workbook_SheetChange event) with the sheet name and address
    '   of your static cell.
    If Sh.Name = myStaticCell.Parent.Name And _
            Target.Address = myStaticCell.Address Then Exit Sub

    ' Save the value to a public variable so it can
    '   be checked the next time something changes.
    myVar = myFormulaCell.Value

    ' If different, update the static cell with the
    '   value from your formula.
    If myStaticCell <> myVar Then myStaticCell = myFormulaCell.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, I'm not sure I fully understand how the event works.  If I'm understanding this properly, does the event check for differences between two sets of cells and then updates the master cell if the supporting cell is different?  If so, I like the process behind how this could work.  It doesn't quite fit what I need for this spreadsheet because the code will only be run once, and if changes are made after the code is run I would like the changes to be automatically updated.  But I can see potential for this type of code working in other sheets.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Elliott, the `Workbook_SheetChange` event is built into Excel.  It won't work if you change the name of the sub.  The event is triggered by an actual change to any cell in the workbook or by an event that causes formulas to update, even if no values are changed (for example, entering the formula bar and pressing enter without changing anything).  All of the code inside the sub is what happens when it is triggered but the actual trigger is something behind the scenes that happens when you use a sub called `Workbook_SheetChange` in your workbook module.

Comment: I still don't fully understand how it works, but I will definitely be doing some Google searches to learn more about it.  Thanks for the great tip and idea.  Have a great day.